# Setting property value with no setter using PrivateObject

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

Using a `PrivateObject`, I'm trying to create an instance of the `ItemChange` class (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemchange_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)). Looking through the debugger as well as the object browser in Visual Studio 2008 I can't seem to find *anything* related to the `ItemId` property other than a setter. Below is the code I am using.

```
var itemChange = new PrivateObject(typeof(ItemChange));

itemChange.SetFieldOrProperty("ChangeType", _fixture.CreateAnonymous<ChangeType>());
itemChange.SetFieldOrProperty("ItemId", _fixture.CreateAnonymous<ItemId>());
```

The error I receive is:

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemChange.ItemId' not found.
```

I've tried variations of `BindingFlags`, however nothing seems to help. How can I set a property that has no setter and only a getter?

#### Edit

Regarding my comments, the other inline class that I can create a `PrivateObject` object instance and set the `ItemId` is the `ItemEvent` class (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemevent_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)). This class was easy because when I was debugging and added the class to my watch list I could see `itemId` as a private variable. However, performing the same steps on the `ItemChange` class I *cannot* find *any* traces of an `ItemId` field other than the property itself that *only* has a setter. This is where I'm stumped on how to set this property.

Lastly, I don't have access to a tool that would allow me to decompile the class and see what is what.

Comment: It's a little bit tricky and it can fail if you change the implementation but can you use Reflection?

Comment: I thought `PrivateObject` was a wrapper around all that reflection stuff, no?

Comment: You need to try and set the private variable, as it is you are trying to set the public one which is failing.

Comment: If you provide a property name it can't understand what's the _backing store_.

Comment: @Adriano: That's what I meant when I said that I can't find anything related to `ItemId` when I debugging. There are other inline classes that I can create private objects of. If I debug I can see there are fields called `_itemId`.

Comment: So then does `itemChange.SetFieldOrProperty("_itemId", _fixture.CreateAnonymous<ItemId>());` work?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: Unfortunately not. Please see edit.

Comment: helpful hint: when digging into the guts of a class, don't stop until you hit `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property you are trying to set is read-only and not backed by any underlying private field, then you can't actually set it. For example, if you had the following property:

```
public string ItemId
{
  get 
  {
    return "Test";
  }
}
```

nothing you do is ever going to set this property to another value. If you don't see an obvious backing field when you look through the object's fields in the debugger and/or reflection, this is likely the situation.

In this case, if I had to make a guess, I would say that ItemId is probably a shortcut property that simply returns `this.Item.Id`.

EDIT:

I was partly true. According to dotPeek, `ItemChange.ItemId` just returns `Change.id`, appropriately typecast. If `Change.serviceObject` has a value, than `Change.id` returns `Change.serviceObject.GetId()`, otherwise it returns `Change.id`. Which of those is appropriate in your case depends on the kind of change you're talking about, per MSDN:

> Item is null when the ChangeType property has a value of either ChangeType.Delete or ChangeType.ReadFlagChange.

Effectively, the implementation of Change and ItemChange does something like this:

```
public class Base 
{
  private Thing thing;
  private BaseId id;

  internal BaseId Id
  {
    get
    {
      return this.thing == null ? this.id : this.thing.GetId();
    }
  }
}

public class Child
{
  public ChildId ChildId
  {
    get 
    { 
      return (ChildId) this.Id; 
    }
  }
}
```

In the actual `Change` implementation, the object field is a [`ServiceObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd636097%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) named `serviceObject`, which has a `GetId()` method that returns a `ServiceId`, and there is also an `id` field of type `ServiceId`. To get your `ItemChange` object's `ItemId` property set, you need to set one or the other of those internal fields on the object's base class (the `serviceObject` field takes precedence if it's set.)

Comment: That makes total sense. I hadn't thought of that before. If it's not too much of a hassle, do you think you could post the code for `ItemChange` and `Change` that was received from dotPeek? Until I go through the proper channels to have dotPeek installed it'll be a few weeks. Thank you.

Comment: I am hesitant to post that code because it is Microsoft copyrighted code and not part of a publically released reference source. However, the implementation is simple, I will add in a similar example that should get you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

A public get-only property does not necessarily have private setter.  If you have not authored the target class yourself, you will probably need to grab a decompiler like [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to figure out what you need to change in order to change the value returned by the property getter.

If you find yourself needing to do this sort of thing often, you might want to consider using an alternate approach to control the behaviour of third-party code without appropriate extension hooks.  For example, [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) would allow you to substitute your own desired behaviour for the getter without knowing anything about the innards of the property or the class.